# Как достать значение из массива (или что это, черт возьми) PHP

Tags: php

Вот что я имею после json_decode:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 37351 [name] => Allex [rank] => 172 [score] => 769.4748211042 [nationality] => stdClass Object ( [country_code] => RU [nation] => Russian Federation [subdivision] => ) ) )
```

Изначально я имею это:

```
[{"id":37351,"name":"Allex","rank":172,"score":769.4748211042013,"nationality":{"country_code":"RU","nation":"Russian Federation","subdivision":null}}]
```

Что мне с этим, черт возьми, сделать, чтобы достать, например, score или name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $result[0]->name
```

попробуйте так должно работать

Comment: не работает, показывает так же всю строку, как и без "[0]->name"

Answer (score 0):

Решение:
$result = json_decode($result, false);
echo $result[0]->name;

За подсказку спасибо парню выше, это я затупил

Comment: так и приняли бы его ответ (Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое), а это в комментарий к нему написали бы (это комментарий в рамках стандартной проверки "первых сообщений").

Comment: а ведь можно было бы и true.....чтобы не видеть это странное страшное чудище в виде stdClass